# Android - Problem with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I needs to make a call to a webservice for 5 times(as there are 5 different parameters) one by one or all at once. Once a particular call completed, in background a textview should be updated with text as: "1st completed", "2nd Completed" and so on.

TextView value should be updated in background.

What should i do ? I am knowing the concept of AsyncTask, but i am confused that should i write 5 AsyncTask and then for each i write execute() method to execute the AsyncTask?

I am successful for only 1 one call, as i set "1st completed" in postExecute() method. But confused for the 5 times call.

Please suggest me a better way or exact solution.

Comment: If the webservice  takes parameters of same type for the 5 calls, one AsyncTask can be used to create 5 async task objects and execute them and update the textview post execution of async task.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You only need 1 AsyncTask, you have to do all 5 calls in the `doInBackground()` and everytime you complete one call the `publishProgress` passing for example the number of the completed call, then, at the end do whatever you need in `onPostExecute`.

A simple approach:

```
private class ServiceCallTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //prepare whatever you need
        myTextField.setText("starting calls");
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        //process params as you need and make the calls
        doCall1();
        publishProgress(1); //this calls onProgressUpdate(1)
        doCall2();
        publishProgress(2);
        doCall3();
        publishProgress(3);
        doCall4();
        publishProgress(4);
        doCall5();
        publishProgress(5);
        return;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        //this runs in UI thread so its safe to modify the UI
        myTextField.append("finished call " + progress);
    }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        myTextField.append("all calls finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: @maid450 Let me check and implement this way. Thanx Thanx Thanx Thanx for the quick support.

Comment: I writted it on the fly and I can't test it right now so there is maybe small syntax mistakes, just let me know if you have problems

Comment: @maid450 Thanx a lot for your code, but one problem: i have called Progressbar.show() method in onPreExecute() and i have written Progressbar.dismiss() method in onPostExecute() method. It is showing Yellow line under the onPostExecute() method.(indicating that it is never used locally) thats why i think ProgressBar is not being dismissed.

Comment: make sure you keep the reference to the ProgressBar that you get when you call `.show()` and then you call `.dismiss()` to this same reference. I usually store the ProgressBar reference in a private class member and I show/dismiss it when I need.

Comment: I just changed onPostExecute(Void unused) and it is working fine. My code is:  protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) 
        {
        try
          {
             if(Dialog.isShowing())
             {
              Dialog.dismiss();
             }
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              
          }
          
         }

Comment: @maid450 Thank you so much. You have made a light quickly and saved my lots of time. Once again thank you so much for your quick response.

Comment: you are welcomed :) that is the kind of mistakes I talked about... I update my code.

Comment: @maid450 i think we need to write "Void unused" in my case, otherwise it is running fine for your code: myTextField.append("all calls finished");, it is running fine without passing "Void unused"